# Lexical binding and other binding concepts in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I'm trying to wrap my head around the concept of binding in Javascript.

Can you explain lexical binding, dynamic binding and other binding techniques in Javascript?

How different is Javascript from Lisp? I don't know Lisp, but my search results in that link.

Thank you very much.

EDIT 1:
Why does this work without the need of using `var that = this;` ?

```
function Person(name){
    this.name = name;
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(this.name);
    }, 100);
}

var me = new Person('Pristine'); // prints "Pristine"
```

If I throw a `function()` in lieu of `()`, I will get an error.

What is lexical binding and scoping? Some further examples, good use cases taking advantage of it?

Comment: There are good resources out there, read them and/or ask more specific questions what you want to know. Your question is a bit broad and will start discussions

Comment: Stack Overflow is for more focused "right or wrong" types of questions. It's not really much of a discussion board. Be sure to check out [the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to find out what is on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Directly to your arrow function question. They bind to the calling scopes context. So you don't have to do ' var that = this'.

Comment: I think you're confusing the concept of binding and scoping. The example you included is irrelevant to your question. For binding, you can view my answer's explanation. For scoping, you should checkout https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science) Scoping is an entirely different concept that's applicable at the programming stage when the programmer has to take into account the scope of objects and functions.

@ste2425 answered your question about the code you provided.

Answer (score 1):

At a very high level, binding is the concept of associating objects or functions with names during compilation or runtime.

e.g. Abstractly speaking, the function in regard to `function foo` isn't associated with the name "foo" until binding happens.

**Lexical binding** (AKA static or early binding) involves associating names during compilation, building data structures known as "v-tables." (V-tables are sets of offsets for the program to look-up variables and methods)

**Dynamic binding** (AKA late binding) involves associating names during runtime. With dynamic binding, there are no v-tables. Names are instead looked-up and associated directly as the program runs.